# Silver background showing between LaunchImage and TabBarViewController

Tags: swift, tvos

My tvOS app does not have or need a proper login screen but I do have a check that is called from AppDelegate at first launch. The issue I am having is while the checkUser is happening with my backend the entire app turns to a silver color. Is there anything I can do about this? I have checked all viewcontroller backgrounds and I dont believe they are causing this. If I cannot fix this I'm wondering I wouldn't mind it being black instead but have no idea what causes this.

Flow: LaunchImage > (silver bg I want to remove during AppDelagate) > TabBarViewController/FirstViewController

In my AppDelegate...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     checkUser(); 
}

func checkUser() {
    //If user is valid...
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController")
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `rootViewController` to something that you want to appear at the start (often apps will match their launch screen) before you call `checkUser()`. Then you can set the `rootViewController` to your `TabBarViewController` in the `checkUser()` when ready.

There's no reason you can't change the `rootViewController` many times during your app's life time.